# Priority highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight

In my code, something like

```
#include <whatever>
```

is highlighted: `#include` (which belongs to the group 'cInclude') in pink; and `<whatever>` (belonging to the group 'cIncluded') in red.
(**Edit**: `whatever` is any word.)

Also, to highlight the word `vector` according to the 'Type' style (in green) I do the following:

```
:call matchadd('Type','\<vector\>',0)
```

Here, `0` sets the priority to a low value. With this, my intention is that in

```
#include <vector>
```

, `<vector>` is highlighted according to the group 'cIncluded', and **not** according to the group 'Type'.

Unexpectedly, I do not get that result. The highlight for `<vector>` in `#include <vector>` turns out to be:

`<` in red (as in the group 'cIncluded')

`vector` in green (as in the group 'Type')

`>` in red (as in the group 'cIncluded')

Why?

Comment: `\<` and `\>` actually mean `start-of-word` and `end-of-word` in Vims regexp

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I only want to highlight the word 'vector' when it is alone, but I do not want to highlight it inside the word 'vectorize', for example.

Comment: But you most likely want to have the `<` and `>` also included in your match, if I understand the question correctly, right?

Comment: I want `vector` to be highlighted in green everywhere in the code except in the excerpt `#include <vector>`, where it should be highlighted in red. And I do not want `vectorize` to be highlighted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`help matchadd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#matchadd()):

> Syntax highlighting (see 'syntax') is a separate
>   mechanism, and regardless of the chosen priority a match will
>   always overrule syntax highlighting.

To match everywhere except certain contexts, you can use [zero-width atoms](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/zero-width):

```
:call matchadd('Type', '\(#include <\)\@<!\<vector\>')
:call matchadd('Type', '\<vector\>\(>\)\@!')
```

The first matches the complete word `vector` if not preceded by `#include <`, and the second matches when it's not followed by `>`.  Together, these should cover all occurrences of the word other than inside `#include <vector>`.

Comment: Thank you for the workaround. However, my question is why the priority that I set does not work.

Comment: Edited to add the relevant excerpt from the docs

Answer (score 4):

I would consider using syntax matching instead of `matchadd()` for this:

```
:syntax match Type /\<vector\>/
```

Because you are *not* specifying `containedin`, this will not match inside the `cIncluded` group that already exists. See `:help :syn-containedin`.

Comment: This is the best way to get the highlighting that I was looking for.